# Extracting Questions and answers from any webpage's faq section using pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-extraction, nlp-question-answering

I want to extract questions and answers from any **webpage's FAQ section**.

An example:
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/faqs/
https://one.google.com/faq

Currently I do this using regex parsing of html content of the page but thats very fragile, and only work 60% of the time. This is because website dont follow any standerd approach while writing their markup. So its hard to write a regex based solution that works for all of them.

I want to know if its possible to do this via ML.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I think what you are asking is not that simple.

You could definetly try to train an algorithm to identify specific Q&A parts of websites, and extract them. This however would involve using relevant data to train the algorithm, which can be hard to find.

Searching for research on this topic in Google Scholar for example, is always a good idea.

As an example see [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2013/ZhouMashuq-WebContentExtractionThroughMachineLearning.pdf).

That being said, if I were to approach this issue, I would follow a different path:

1. Extract all the text from a webpage
2. Try to analyze the text to see whether it is Q&A text

This approach might not be optimal but feels easier because there are numerous resources (`NLTK`, `spaCy`, `scikit-learn`) for analyzing and manupulating text.

- Using one of these resources you could apply heuristic rules to determine if the text is Q&A (category).
- Alternatively you could treat this problem as a classification task and train a supervised algorithm (e.g. `Naive Bayes`, `SVM`, `kNN`, among others) to determine if a piece of text is Q&A or not.

Feel free to add information in your question or comment, in case I can provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to try extracting questions and answers from webpages using ML models, your best bet would be to use one of those huge pre-trained language models out there, like [OpenAI GPT3](https://beta.openai.com/docs/models/overview).

The following code is an example on how you could try to use GPT3 to try to extract QAs from a general website:

**Note:** you need an API Key to be able to run this solution.

```py
"""
Define the `CodexQAExtractor` class, that extracts questions and answers from
website pages.

.. attention::

   To use this code you need to have an OpenAI account and an API key.
   In addition, you need to install the `openai` package:

    .. code-block:: bash

         $ pip install openai

How to use
----------
The following code exemplifies how you can use this code to extract questions and answers from website pages:

.. code-block:: python

    extractor = CodexQAExtractor(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
    response = extractor.extract_qa_from_url(url_link)

"""
from __future__ import annotations

import os.path
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import requests
import openai


if OPENAI_API_KEY := os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"):
    openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY


def read_from_url(url_text: str) -> str | None:
    """Read text from a URL.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url_text : str
        URL to read from.

    Returns
    -------
    str | None
        Text read from the URL, if `url_text` is a valid URL.
    """
    try:
        file = requests.get(url_text)
        return file.text
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        print(
            f'Failed to read url: "{url_text}". '
            "See the above exception message for more details."
        )


def extract_text_from_html(html_text: str) -> str | None:
    """Extract text from HTML.

    Parameters
    ----------
    html_text : str
        HTML to extract text from.

    Returns
    -------
    str | None
        Text extracted from the HTML, if `html_text` is valid HTML.
    """
    contents = html_text.split("<body")[1].split(">", 1)[1].split("</body")[0]
    parsed = []
    for text in contents.split(">"):
        if "</" in text:
            new_text = text.split("</")[0].replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
            while "  " in new_text:
                new_text = new_text.replace("  ", " ")
            while len(new_text) > 0 and new_text[0] == " ":
                new_text = new_text[1:]
            if len(new_text) > 5:
                parsed.append(new_text)
    return ";".join(parsed)


def is_authenticated() -> bool:
    """Check if the user is authenticated with OpenAI.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        `True` if the user is authenticated with OpenAI.
    """
    return len(openai.api_key) > 0


def is_float_norm(*args) -> bool:
    """Check if the arguments are floats between 0 and 1.

    Parameters
    ----------
    args : float
        Arguments to check.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        `True` if the arguments are numbers between 0 and 1.

    Notes
    -----
    Function used for verifying the parameters that the user specified to
    the `CodexQAExtractor.extract_qa` method.
    """
    return not any(
        not isinstance(arg, float) or not 0 <= arg <= 1 for arg in args
    )


class CodexQAExtractor:
    """
    Class to extract questions and answers from a text derived from website.

    Parameters
    ----------
    response_dir : str, default "./answers"
        Directory to save the responses.
    openai_api_key : str | None, default None
        OpenAI API key to use. If `None`, class assumes that the API key is
        already set.

    Attributes
    ----------
    response_dir : str
        Directory to save the responses.

    Methods
    -------
    get_response_filename()
        Get the filename to save the response to.
    extract_qa_from_url(url_text: str, **kwargs) -> str | None
        Extract questions and answers from a URL.
    extract_qa(text: str, **kwargs) -> str | None
        Extract questions and answers from a text.
    """

    def __init__(
        self, response_dir: str = "./answers", openai_api_key: str | None = None
    ):
        if openai_api_key is not None:
            openai.api_key = openai_api_key
        Path(response_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        self.response_dir = response_dir

    def get_response_filename(self) -> str:
        """Get the filename to save the response to."""
        next_index = int(len(list(Path(self.response_dir).glob("*.txt"))) + 1)
        return f"{self.response_dir}{os.path.sep}answer_{next_index}.txt"

    def extract_qa(
        self,
        parsed_text: str,
        temperature: float = 0.0,
        top_p: float = 1.0,
        frequency_penalty: float = 0.0,
        presence_penalty: float = 0.0,
        best_of: int = 1,
        max_tokens: int | None = None,
        verbose: bool = True,
        **kwargs,  # noqa
    ) -> str:
        """Extract questions and answers from a text.

        Parameters
        ----------
        parsed_text : str
            Text to extract questions and answers from.
        temperature : float, default 0.0
            Temperature for the probability distribution used to sample
            different tokens at each step. Must be between 0 and 1.
        top_p : float, default 1.0
            The cumulative probability for top-p sampling. Must be between 0
            and 1.
        frequency_penalty : float, default 0.0
            The probability of a token being penalized if it appears too
            frequently in the current sequence. Must be between 0 and 1.
        presence_penalty : float, default 0.0
            The probability of a token being penalized if it appears in the
            current sequence. Must be between 0 and 1.
        best_of : int, default 1
            Number of responses to generate and return.
        max_tokens : int | None, default None
            Maximum number of tokens to generate. If `None`, the number of
            tokens is set by the method.
        verbose : bool, default True
            Whether to print the response to the console.

        Returns
        -------
        str
            Extracted questions and answers from `parsed_text`.

        Raises
        ------
        ValueError
            - If `temperature`, `top_p`, `frequency_penalty`, `presence_penalty`
            are not between 0 and 1.
            - If `best_of` is not a positive integer between 1 and 20.
            - If `max_tokens` is not a positive integer between 1 and 8000.
            - If prompt contains more than 8000 tokens.

        Notes
        -----
        Method assumes that `parsed_text` contains text that was already
        preprocessed, and is not pure HTML string. You can use the function
        `extract_text_from_html` to extract text from HTML:

            .. code-block:: python

                parsed_text = extract_text_from_html(html_text)

        """
        if not is_authenticated():
            raise ValueError(
                "OpenAI API key is not set. Inform a valid token using the "
                "parameter `openai_api_key` from `CodexQAExtractor` class, or "
                "set it as follows:\n\n\timport openai\n\topenai.api_key = "
                '"YOUR_API_KEY"\n'
            )

        if not is_float_norm(
            temperature, top_p, frequency_penalty, presence_penalty
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                "Parameters `temperature`, `top_p`, `frequency_penalty`, "
                "`presence_penalty` must be between 0 and 1. Got\n"
                f"- temperature: {temperature}\n"
                f"- top_p: {top_p}\n"
                f"- frequency_penalty: {frequency_penalty}\n"
                f"- presence_penalty: {presence_penalty}\n"
            )
        if not isinstance(best_of, int) or not 1 <= best_of <= 20:
            raise ValueError(
                "Parameter `best_of` must be an integer between 1 and 20. "
                f"Got: {best_of} of type {type(best_of)}."
            )
        prompt = (
            '# Extract questions and answers from the following text:\n"""\n'
            f'{parsed_text}"""\n###\n"""\nQ:'
        )
        # Prompt exceeds the maximum number of tokens that you can use for a single prompt.
        if len(prompt) > 32000:
            lowbound = 0
            final_response = ""
            # Breaking `parsed_text` smaller parts and extracting QA's from
            # each separately. This most likely will make the result
            # a lot worse...
            # Note: you could try overcome this by including some of
            #       the text from the previous iteration into the new one.
            for upbound in np.arange(5000, len(parsed_text)+1, 5000):
                final_response += self.extract_qa(
                    parsed_text[lowbound: upbound],
                    temperature,
                    top_p,
                    frequency_penalty,
                    presence_penalty,
                    best_of,
                    max_tokens,
                    verbose,
                )
                lowbound = upbound
            return final_response
                    
        if max_tokens is None:
            max_tokens = int((8_000 - len(prompt) / 4) * 0.65)
        if not isinstance(max_tokens, int) or not 1 <= max_tokens <= 8_000:
            raise ValueError(
                "Parameter `max_tokens` must be an integer between 1 and 8000. "
                f"Got: {max_tokens} of type {type(max_tokens)}."
            )
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            model="code-davinci-002",
            prompt=prompt,
            temperature=temperature,
            max_tokens=max_tokens,
            top_p=top_p,
            frequency_penalty=frequency_penalty,
            presence_penalty=presence_penalty,
            best_of=best_of,
            stop=['"""', "###"],
        )["choices"][0]["text"]

        response = f"Q:{response}"

        with open(self.get_response_filename(), "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(response)
        if verbose:
            print(response)
        return response

    def extract_qa_from_url(self, url_text: str, **kwargs) -> str | None:
        """Extract questions and answers from the given URL.

        Method retrieves the HTML element from the `url_text`, then extracts
        relevant text from the HTML code before calling
        `CodexQAExtractor.extract_qa` to extract the questions and answers
        from the HTML code.

        Parameters
        ----------
        url_text : str
            URL to extract questions and answers from.
        kwargs : Any
            Additional arguments to pass to the `CodexQAExtractor.extract_qa`
            method.

        Returns
        -------
        str
            The extracted questions and answers from the URL.
        """
        html_text = read_from_url(url_text)
        if html_text is None:
            print("Failed to download the HTML elements from the URL, or"
                  "parse its text.")
            return
        page_contents = extract_text_from_html(html_text)
        return self.extract_qa(page_contents, **kwargs)
```

Extracting questions and answers from the website that you gave as example:

```py
qa_model = CodexQAExtractor()
test_url = "https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/faqs/?nc1=h_ls"
res = qa_model.extract_qa_from_url(test_url)


# Outputs:
# Q: What is Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling?
# A: Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling is a service designed to automatically launch or terminate Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances based on user-defined policies, schedules, and health checks. Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps you ensure that you have the correct number of Amazon EC2 instances available to handle the load for your application.
# 
# Q. When should I use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling vs. AWS Auto Scaling?
# A. You should use AWS Auto Scaling to manage scaling for multiple resources across multiple services. AWS Auto Scaling lets you define dynamic scaling policies for multiple EC2 Auto Scaling groups or other resources using predefined scaling strategies. Using AWS Auto Scaling to configure scaling policies for all of the scalable resources in your application is faster than managing scaling policies for each resource via its individual service console. It’s also easier, as AWS Auto Scaling includes predefined scaling strategies that simplify the setup of scaling policies.&nbsp;
# 
# You should use EC2 Auto Scaling if you only need to scale Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups, or if you are only interested in maintaining the health of your EC2 fleet. You should also use EC2 Auto Scaling if you need to create or configure Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups, or if you need to set up scheduled or step scaling policies (as AWS Auto Scaling supports only target tracking scaling policies).
# 
# Q: How is Predictive Scaling Policy different from Predictive Scaling of AWS Auto Scaling plan?
# A: Predictive Scaling Policy is a feature of Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling that predicts future demand and automatically scales your Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group in advance of anticipated load. Predictive Scaling of AWS Auto Scaling plan is a feature of AWS Auto Scaling that predicts future demand and automatically scales your AWS Auto Scaling plan in advance of anticipated load.
# 
# Q: What are the benefits of using Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling?
# A: Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps you maintain application availability and allows you to scale your Amazon EC2 capacity up or down automatically according to conditions you define. You can use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling for fleet management of EC2 instances to help maintain the health and availability of your fleet and ensure that you are running your desired number of instances. Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can also automatically increase the number of Amazon EC2 instances during demand spikes to maintain performance and decrease capacity during lulls to reduce costs.
# 
# Q: What is fleet management and how is it different from dynamic scaling?
# A: Fleet management is the process of maintaining the health of your Amazon EC2 fleet. Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps you maintain the health of your fleet by automatically replacing unhealthy instances. If an instance becomes unhealthy, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling terminates the unhealthy instance and launches an instance to replace it.
# 
# Dynamic scaling refers to the functionality that automatically increases or decreases capacity based on load or other metrics. For example, if your CPU spikes above 80% (and you have an alarm setup)&nbsp;Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can add a new instance dynamically.
# 
# Q: What is target tracking?
# A: Target tracking is a scaling policy that lets you set a target value for a specific metric. Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling creates and manages the CloudWatch alarms that trigger the scaling policy and calculates the scaling adjustment based on the metric and the target value. The scaling policy adds or removes capacity as required to keep the metric at, or close to, the specified target value.
# 
# Q: What is an EC2 Auto Scaling group (ASG)?
# A: An EC2 Auto Scaling group contains a collection of Amazon EC2 instances that share similar characteristics and are treated as a logical grouping for the purposes of automatic scaling and management. For example, you might have an EC2 Auto Scaling group for a web application that serves traffic to your users.
# 
# Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling User Guide
# 
# Q: What happens to my Amazon EC2 instances if I delete my ASG?
# A: If you have an EC2 Auto Scaling group (ASG) with running instances and you choose to delete the ASG, the instances will be terminated and the ASG will be deleted.
# 
# Q: How do I know when EC2 Auto Scaling is launching or terminating the EC2 instances in an EC2 Auto Scaling group?
# A: Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) is a web service that coordinates and manages the delivery or sending of notifications to subscribing clients or endpoints. You can configure EC2 Auto Scaling to send an SNS notification whenever your EC2 Auto Scaling group scales. Amazon SNS can deliver notifications as HTTP or HTTPS POST, email (SMTP, either plain-text or in JSON format), or as a message posted to an Amazon SQS queue. For example, if you configure your EC2 Auto Scaling group to use the autoscaling: EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE notification type, and your EC2 Auto Scaling group terminates an instance, it sends an email notification. This email contains the details of the terminated instance, such as the instance ID and the reason that the instance was terminated.
# 
# Getting SNS Notifications when your EC2 Auto Scaling Group Scales
# 
# Q: What is a launch configuration?
# A: A launch configuration is a template that an EC2 Auto Scaling group uses to launch EC2 instances. In addition to the launch configuration, you must specify the maximum and minimum size of the group. With this information, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can launch or terminate instances as demand on your application increases or decreases.
# 
# Q: How many instances can an EC2 Auto Scaling group have?
# A: An EC2 Auto Scaling group can have a minimum size of 0 and a maximum size of 1,000.
# 
# Q: What happens if a scaling activity causes me to reach my Amazon EC2 limit of instances?
# A: If you reach your Amazon EC2 limit of instances, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling will not launch any more instances. You can request an Amazon EC2 limit increase by submitting an Amazon EC2 instance request form.
# 
# Amazon EC2 instance request form
# 
# Q: Can EC2 Auto Scaling groups span multiple AWS regions?
# A: No. An EC2 Auto Scaling group is associated with a single region.
# 
# Q: How can I implement changes across multiple instances in an EC2 Auto Scaling group?
# A: You can use AWS CodeDeploy or CloudFormation to orchestrate code changes to multiple instances in your EC2 Auto Scaling group.
# 
# Q: If I have data installed in an EC2 Auto Scaling group, and a new instance is dynamically created later, is the data copied over to the new instances?
# A: No. If you have data installed on an EC2 instance, and a new instance is dynamically created later, the data is not copied over to the new instances. You can use lifecycle hooks to copy the data off of a stateful instance before it’s terminated, or enable instance protection to prevent Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling from terminating it.
# 
# Replacing Impaired Instances
# 
# Q: How does Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling replace an impaired instance?
# A: Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling replaces an impaired instance by terminating the impaired instance and launching a new instance.
# 
# Q: How do I control which instances Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling terminates when scaling in, and how do I protect data on an instance?
# A: You can use instance protection to prevent Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling from terminating an instance when it scales in. You can also use lifecycle hooks to copy the data off of a stateful instance before it’s terminated.
# 
# Q: How long is the turn-around time for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling to spin up a new instance at inService state after detecting an unhealthy server?
# A: The turn-around time depends on the instance type and the AMI used.
# 
# Q: If Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) determines that an instance is unhealthy, and moved offline, will the previous requests sent to the failed instance be queued and rerouted to other instances within the group?
# A: No. If an instance is unhealthy, it is terminated and replaced by Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling.
# 
# Q: If you don’t use Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) how would users be directed to the other servers in a group if there was a failure?
# A: If you don’t use Elastic Load Balancing (ELB), you can use Amazon Route 53 to route traffic to the other servers in a group.
# 
# Security
# 
# Q: How do I control access to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling resources?
# A: You can use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM), a service that enables you to do the following:
# 
# Create users and groups under your organization's AWS account
# Assign unique security credentials to each user under your AWS account
# Control each user's permissions to perform tasks using AWS resources
# Allow the users in another AWS account to share your AWS resources
# Create roles for your AWS account and define the users or services that can assume them
# You can use IAM to control access to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling resources at the following levels:
# 
# AWS account level—You can grant or deny a user permission to perform all Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling actions.
# Resource level—You can grant or deny a user permission to perform specific actions on specific Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling resources. For example, you could grant a user permission to use the DescribeAutoScalingGroups, DescribeLaunchConfigurations, DescribeScalingActivities, and DescribePolicies API operations. Users in the Managers group could then use those operations with any Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups and launch configurations. With Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling resource-level permissions, you can restrict access to a particular EC2 Auto Scaling group or launch configuration.
# 
# Controlling Access to Your Auto Scaling Resources
# 
# Q: Can you define a default admin password on Windows instances with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling?
# A: Yes. You can use the GetPasswordData API to retrieve the password data for a Windows instance, and then decrypt the password using the key pair that you specified when you launched the instance.
# 
# GetPasswordData
# 
# Q: Are CloudWatch agents automatically installed on EC2 instances when you create an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group?
# A: No. You must install the CloudWatch agent on your EC2 instances.
# 
# Cost Optimization
# 
# Q: Can I create a single ASG to scale instances across different purchase options?
# A: Yes. You can configure your ASG specifying all capacity to be only Spot instances or all capacity to be only On-Demand instances and RIs.
# 
# Yes. When setting up an ASG to combine purchasing models, you can specify the base capacity of the group to be fulfilled by On-Demand instances. As the ASG scales in or scale out, EC2 Auto Scaling ensures the base capacity be fulfilled with On-Demand instances and anything beyond that be fulfilled with either only Spot instances or a specified percentage mix of On-Demand or Spot instances.
# 
# Yes. Similar to other ASG parameters, customers can update an existing ASG to modify one or all parameters pertaining to combining purchasing models and specifying multiple instance types, including instance types, prioritization order for On-Demand instances, percentage split between On-Demand and Spot instances, and allocation strategy.
# 
# Yes. For example, if you have RIs for C4 instances and EC2 Auto Scaling launches a C4 you will receive your RI pricing for On-Demand Instances.
# 
# If none of the specified instance types are available in an Availability Zone, Auto Scaling will retarget the launches in other Availability Zones associated with the Auto Scaling group. Auto Scaling will always prefer keeping your compute balanced across Availability Zones and retarget if all instance types are not available in an Availability Zone.
# 
# Pricing
# 
# Q: What are the costs for using Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling?
# A: There is no additional charge for using Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling. You pay for the AWS resources that you create to store and run your application. For more information, see Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling pricing.
```

Another example using Azure FAQ website:

Webpage being tested: https://support.azure.cn/en-us/support/faq/

```py
test_url2 = r"https://support.azure.cn/en-us/support/faq/"
qa_model.extract_qa_from_url(test_url2)
```

Output:

[image]